# Integrating Doctrine with CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, doctrine-orm

I have successfully installed the latest version of CodeIgniter and have basic MVC pattern working. The problem that I've noticed is that CI doesn't naturally allow for prepared statements when it comes to queries. So, I decided to download Doctrine 1 from [GitHub](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2). I'm very new to Doctrine and needed some help integrating it with CI so I followed this [tutorial](http://wildlyinaccurate.com/integrating-doctrine-2-with-codeigniter-2).

In one of my controllers, I have

```
$this->load->library('doctrine');
$this->em = $this->doctrine->em;
```

But, when I go to load the view in my browser, I'm greeted with an error reading

> Message: require_once(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/CodeIgniter/application/libraries/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Upon further inspection of the Doctrine download from GitHub, there doesn't even seem to be a folder titled "common" anywhere in there. I'm very new to CI and especially Doctrine. Does anyone have some advice that can help me get this working? Also, is it possible to use the MySQLi driver instead of the PDO one with Doctrine?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Downloading the Doctrine ORM straight from GitHub doesn't include the other dependencies. These are managed by [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md). If you look inside the composer.json file you can see these dependencies. If you want to install them manually, they are:

- doctrine/common
- doctrine/inflector
- doctrine/cache
- doctrine/collections
- doctrine/lexer
- doctrine/annotations
- doctrine/dbal
- symfony/console

I believe that's all of them. You will have to merge these files in their appropriate directories as they follow [PSR-0 standards](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) for the autoloading of classes.

Alternatively, install Doctrine 2 with Composer with the following composer.json file and any other dependencies will be installed automatically. Then [integrate with CodeIgniter](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2012/05/composer-with-codeigniter).

```
{
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "doctrine/orm": "2.3.*"
    }
}
```

Edit the `index.php` file of your CodeIgniter app by adding a single line to include the autoloader file before requiring the CodeIgniter core.

```
require_once BASEPATH.'../vendor/autoload.php';

require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

Also if installing with Composer, use this edited version of the bootstrap as the contents of `application/libraries/Doctrine.php`, which is what worked for me

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader,
    Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup,
    Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class Doctrine
{
    public $em;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Load the database configuration from CodeIgniter
        require APPPATH . 'config/database.php';

        $connection_options = array(
            'driver'        => 'pdo_mysql',
            'user'          => $db['default']['username'],
            'password'      => $db['default']['password'],
            'host'          => $db['default']['hostname'],
            'dbname'        => $db['default']['database'],
            'charset'       => $db['default']['char_set'],
            'driverOptions' => array(
                'charset'   => $db['default']['char_set'],
            ),
        );

        // With this configuration, your model files need to be in application/models/Entity
        // e.g. Creating a new Entity\User loads the class from application/models/Entity/User.php
        $models_namespace = 'Entity';
        $models_path = APPPATH . 'models';
        $proxies_dir = APPPATH . 'models/Proxies';
        $metadata_paths = array(APPPATH . 'models');

        // Set $dev_mode to TRUE to disable caching while you develop
        $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($metadata_paths, $dev_mode = true, $proxies_dir);
        $this->em = EntityManager::create($connection_options, $config);

        $loader = new ClassLoader($models_namespace, $models_path);
        $loader->register();
    }
}
```

Note: Version 3 of CodeIgniter when released, will be installable with Composer, but version 2 is not.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my initial answer. I saw composer.json in the master branch, but didn't check to see if it was in the 2.1-stable branch. I've corrected it now.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what to do with Composer. There's a json file in the doctrine download, but that's it.

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for a tutorial to integrate Doctrine 2 with CodeIgniter, this question and others answers are outdated (for CI 2).
This is a new tutorial for CI 3 I made and I checked is working:

[How to install Doctrine 2 in CodeIgniter 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209930/how-to-install-doctrine-in-codeigniter-3/33209931#33209931)

---

I repeat it here.

**Install Doctrine**

[Doctrine 2 ORM’s documentation -  Installation and Configuration](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#installation-and-configuration)

Doctrine can be installed with [Composer](http://www.getcomposer.org/).
Define the following requirement in your composer.json file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "doctrine/orm": "*"
    }
}
```

Then call composer install from your command line.

**Integrating with CodeIgniter**

[Doctrine 2 ORM’s documentation - Integrating with CodeIgniter](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/integrating-with-codeigniter.html)

Here are the steps:
Add a php file to your system/application/libraries folder called Doctrine.php. This is going to be your wrapper/bootstrap for the D2 entity manager.
Put the Doctrine folder (the one that contains Common, DBAL, and ORM) inside the third_party folder.
If you want, open your config/autoload.php file and autoload your Doctrine library: `$autoload[‘libraries’] = array(‘doctrine’);`

**Creating your Doctrine CodeIgniter library**

Now, here is what your Doctrine.php file should look like. Customize it to your needs.

```
<?php
/**
 * Doctrine 2.4 bootstrap
 *
 */

use Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader,
    Doctrine\ORM\Configuration,
    Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager,
    Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache,
    Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger;


class Doctrine {

  public $em = null;

  public function __construct()
  {
    // load database configuration from CodeIgniter
    require_once APPPATH.'config/database.php';

    // include Doctrine's ClassLoader class
    require_once APPPATH.'third_party/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';

    // load the Doctrine classes        
    $doctrineClassLoader = new ClassLoader('Doctrine',  APPPATH.'third_party');
    $doctrineClassLoader->register();
    // load the entities
    $entityClassLoader = new ClassLoader('Entities', APPPATH.'models');
    $entityClassLoader->register();
    // load the proxy entities
    $proxiesClassLoader = new ClassLoader('Proxies', APPPATH.'models/proxies');
    $proxiesClassLoader->register();
    // load Symfony2 classes
    // this is necessary for YAML mapping files and for Command Line Interface (cli-doctrine.php)
    $symfonyClassLoader = new ClassLoader('Symfony',  APPPATH.'third_party/Doctrine');
    $symfonyClassLoader->register();

    // Set up the configuration
    $config = new Configuration;

    // Set up caches
    if(ENVIRONMENT == 'development')  // set environment in index.php
        // set up simple array caching for development mode
        $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache;
    else
        // set up caching with APC for production mode
        $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache;  
    $config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
    $config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);

    // set up annotation driver
    $driver = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\PHPDriver(APPPATH.'models/Mappings');
    $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driver);

    // Proxy configuration
    $config->setProxyDir(APPPATH.'/models/Proxies');
    $config->setProxyNamespace('Proxies');

    // Set up logger
    $logger = new EchoSQLLogger;
    $config->setSQLLogger($logger);

    $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses( TRUE ); // only for development

    // Database connection information
    $connectionOptions = array(
        'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
        'user' =>     $db['default']['username'],
        'password' => $db['default']['password'],
        'host' =>     $db['default']['hostname'],
        'dbname' =>   $db['default']['database']
    );

    // Create EntityManager, and store it for use in our CodeIgniter controllers
    $this->em = EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);
  }
}
```

**Setting up the Command Line Tool**

Doctrine ships with a number of command line tools that are very helpful during development.

Check if these lines exists in the Doctrine.php file, to load Symfony classes for using the Command line tools (and for YAML mapping files):

```
$symfonyClassLoader = new ClassLoader('Symfony', APPPATH.'third_party/Doctrine');
$symfonyClassLoader->register();
```

You need to register your applications EntityManager to the console tool to make use of the tasks by creating a cli-doctrine.php file in the application directory with the following content:

```
 <?php

 /**
 * Doctrine CLI bootstrap for CodeIgniter
 *
 */

 define('APPPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
define('BASEPATH', APPPATH . '/../system/');
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');

 require APPPATH.'libraries/Doctrine.php';

$doctrine = new Doctrine;
$em = $doctrine->em;

 $helperSet = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet(array(
    'db' => new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($em->getConnection()),
    'em' => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($em)
));

 \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner::run($helperSet);

 ?>
```

Now run this script through the PHP command-line and should see a list of commands available to you.

```
php cli-doctrine.php
```

Generate mapping classes from database:

```
php cli-doctrine.php orm:convert-mapping --from-database annotation models/Entities
```

if you get this error: 
*Fatal error: Call to undefined function Doctrine\Common\Cache\apc_fetch()*
install the APC extension for PHP:

```
sudo apt-get install php-apc
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

For **production mode** you'll want to use a real caching system like APC, get rid of `EchoSqlLogger`, and turn off `autoGenerateProxyClasses` in Doctrine.php

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I followed the advice

Comment: Copy and Pasted contents

Comment: @Abdulla: Daenu said " it is better to include the essential parts of the answer", but you said "Copy and Pasted contents". How can I satisfy either? SO says [Copy and Paste contents is a bad practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78658/is-it-okay-to-copy-paste-answers-from-other-questions) only for  another user's answers, but I copied and pasted my answear!

Comment: So you can falg that as duplicate

Comment: @Abdulla I don't think so, this is a generic question, that's a specific question for CI 3. I think are different. Maybe this is a outdated question asked in 2013, and I warned users that things are changed. Question wording may mislead users.

Answer (score 1):

Find the link for the doctrine integration in CI
https://github.com/mitul69/codeigniter-doctrine-integration

Answer (score 0):

Please note that **code igniter 2** has a little difference in its code organization. In **code igniter 2** it is better to put the `Doctrine` folder in `application/third_party` folder, instead of `application/libraries` folder (or else it will not work!).

You can read more about it [here](http://codesamplez.com/development/using-doctrine-with-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I tried to follow this tutorial from doctrine user guide
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/integrating-with-codeigniter.html

This problem happens when I tried to install via composer so then I went to this web site
http://www.doctrine-project.org/downloads/ and do manually download the DoctrineORM-2.3.3-full.tar.gz version and the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

The original poster's problem seems to be an issue with autoloading. I was presented with a similar issue when trying to set up CodeIgniter and Doctrine with Composer. In CodeIgniter 3, you can enable the use of composer autoloading, which should allow you to load all Doctrine files correctly. You must point your Composer vendor dir to application/vendor for this to work. You can also do it in older versions, but then you have to include the Composer autoload file manually in your Doctrine library file for CodeIgniter.
If you want more information: I wrote a blog post describing exactly how to do it. http://blog.beheist.com/integrating-codeigniter-and-doctrine-2-orm-with-composer/

Comment: Could you please add here some parts of your blog post?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

via composer :
composer create-project rbz/codeigniter your-project

via git :
git clone https://github.com/dandisy/cihmvctwig.git